Combine two queries into columns if join breaks grouping and union combines into rows
how do I combine the results of these queries into columns? join is not suitable, because then in the on condition you will need to compare the id and the grouping will be broken, and union joins into strings. I want to get 4 columns in the result set. is it possible to modify the union operator in some way?
select count (num_zaprosa), num_zaprosa
from osn_sredstva 
where num_zaprosa is not null
group by num_ zaprosa

select count (num_otveta), num_otveta
from osn_sredstva 
where num_otveta is not null 
group by num_otveta

initial data:
num_zaprosa|num_otveta
______________________
 2344      |   200          

  22       |   null  
 
 2344      |    200

 155       |    6

 22        |    9999

what result do I expect:
num_zaprosa|num_otveta| count_num_zaprosa| count_num_otveta |
_____________________________________________________________
 2344      |   200    |        2         |          2       |
_____________________________________________________________
 22        |   9999   |        2         |          1       |
_____________________________________________________________
   155     |     6    |         1        |          1       |



Please tag only a single RDBMS... 2) please always provide a [MRE] with sample data, desired results and your attempt. As already commented on your very recent question.


Didn't you already ask this? The expected results in that question appear to be identical.

Combine how? You group by different columns, so I can't figure out what way you want to present the combined result.

Why not add some sample data and expected result in a text table form? As they say in Hollywood, show don't tell.

I added the desired result

Can you add more than two rows of sample data? So it's possible to understand everything?

@JohnB you've still tagged both SQL Server AND Firebird... which is it?

@JohnB and you haven't explained how this question is different to your previous one... the sample data and desired results are the same.

I've gone ahead and closed this as a duplicate pending a clear and reasonable definition of how it differs.
